# Make div container 100% height in spite of content div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an animated gif in a div with low opacity (`div.animated`) which is like a background to full screen, width and height 100%. However, when I try to put a div (`div.square`) after the first one with a fixed size and position absolute in order to be above it, the upper div (`div.animated`) doesn't adapt its height to full screen.

I cannot use `div.animated` like a container of `div.square` because the first would cover the second with its background animated gif and I need to reduce the opacity of the gif only, not the content.

The position fixed isn't useful for me since I want a responsive web with overflow auto.

To sum up, I need to put a div above another which has a low opacity.

An example what I try to do:

[Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNebEQ)

```
<div class="animated"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: "I cannot use the first div like a container of the second because the first would cover the second with its background animated gif" - why would it be the case? Child element is contained inside its parent

Comment: Just remove the margin from the body? http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/qENWPX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you could do - to force the background `div` to take a full height regardless of the content inside, use the following CSS:

```
#container {
  display:block;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  background:url('http://media.giphy.com/media/SZQslH8yhprFu/giphy.gif') center center no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  overflow:auto;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#content {
  height:auto;
  width:50%;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:rgba(110,110,110,0.75);
  padding:10px;
}
```

Using `overflow:auto` allows the content to scroll while keeping the page background in the same position.

**Here's a [CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/NPrWqq)** showing the result.

Comment: Exactly, that is. Thanks a lot. A greeting!

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Make sure to accept the answer so others know it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

I really tried to interpret your question. But could you call the div's by their names, like: i want `animated` in front of `square`, full width etc...

For the background use something like this for the `body` in CSS:

```
body {
    background: url(img_flwr.gif);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Source: [w3school.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

To put another `div` in a `div` do this in HTML:

```
<div class="animated">
   <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to reduce the opacity of that gif. So, if I make it as you say, I will reduce the opacity of all content. That's the reason why I try to put two different divs, one with the gif and another with the content. The problem is that, like in the example, the .square div overflows over the animated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what you want/need but I use position: fixed and it still responsive...

```
.square{
  background-color: pink;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
}
```

See [CodePen code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwELmL)

**Update:**

If you need .animated have ever more height than .square you coud do something like this, keeping your html and css logic:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var squareArea = $(".square").height() + ($(".square").offset().top * 2);

  if($(".animated").height() < squareArea)
    {
      $("body").height(squareArea);
      $(".animated").height(squareArea);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/7wvga59z/)

Comment: Not exactly. If you change the top position of the div.square, this will overflow over the div.animated. I want that the div.animated (the yellow), has always more height than the div.square (full screen).